# woocommerce cart related issue cart not deleted

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I would like to tell you that I have created cart manually and Now I want "Delete cart" when I used `delete_user_meta($user_id,'woocommerce_cart');`

It delete the cart data in the database but when I refresh website cart comes again and in database cart comes again.

I am trying to solve this issue from past 7 days but i am unable to resolve this.

Thank's !

Comment: Use `WC()->cart->empty_cart()` if you want to remove all items from the cart.

Comment: i want to delete cart by user id in have so many users so i want to delete cart by their user_id

Comment: Do you want to empty all users cart data?

Comment: no i want to empty cart according to user id